# NullReferenceException using String.Contains

Tags: f#

I don't know why I'm getting that Exception on the List.filter part of the following code:

```
pdfLinks |> List.filter(fun x -> x.Contains("shop")) |> List.iter (printfn "%s")
```

pdfLinks is of type "string list" and it is populated with tons of strings that contain the word "shop".

It works ok in F# Interactive with a dummy list. The original one has been generated by parsing an HTML file but inspecting it by a watch shows it has desired values of the desired type.

Any idea what may be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe one of them is null?

Comment: Doesn't seem so... Although I can only look at the first 50 through the Watch. Printing them shows some blank lines which may be due to null values. I'll check for nulls first and get back with an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a call to `System.String.IsNullOrEmpty` into your `List.filter` and see if it fixes the problem:

```
pdfLinks
|> List.filter(fun x ->
    (not <| System.String.IsNullOrEmpty x) &&
    x.Contains("shop"))
|> List.iter (printfn "%s")
```

Comment: That was it. As @ChaosPandion also pointed, I was getting a null string, because it seems the library I'm interacting with returns that as default when it doesn't have a successful string to return. I sometimes forget we don't have the Option commodity when interacting with C# code ;). Thanks a lot!

Comment: When taking input from the 'outside world' it is often best to map to option types, and deal with them appropriately. In your case, take the list of pdf links and map to `string option`, then the rest of your code will automatically work (because you're forced to deal with it).